# How to make the same pattern code more concise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope those code can be more concise, but I don't know how to do that.

the function 2~4 has a same pattern, I hope I can reduce the code,

and also if I have too much "or" and "and", is there any method can make it cleaner?

```
const statusFilter2 = (data1, data2) => {
    if (data1 === 'error' || data2 === 'error') {
        return 'error'
    } else if (data1 === 'C' || C === 'C') {
        return 'A'
    } else if (data1 === 'B' || data2 === 'B') {
        return 'B'
    } else {
        return 'C'
    }
}

const statusFilter3 = (data1, data2, data3) => {

    if (data1 === 'error' || data2 === 'error' || data3 === 'error') {
        return 'error'
    } else if (data1 === 'C' || data2 === 'C' || data3 === 'C') {
        return 'C'
    } else if (data1 === 'B' || data2 === 'B' || data3 === 'B') {
        return 'B'
    } else {
        return 'A'
    }
}


const statusFilter4 = (data1, data2, data3, data4) => {
    if (data1 === 'error' || data2 === 'error' || data3 === 'error' || data4 === 'error') {
        return 'error'
    } else if (data1 === 'C' || data2 === 'C' || data3 === 'C' || data4 === 'C') {
        return 'C'
    } else if (data1 === 'B' || data2 === 'B' || data3 === 'B' || data4 === 'B') {
        return 'B'
    } else {
        return 'A'
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a question more suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow primarily deals in debugging, not in code reviews, which is why there's a separate community for it.

Comment: well they all can be like `statusFilter4`. If the parameter is not set it will be undefined and will not match so it is not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use only one function instead of having three separate functions.

**Code steps explanation**

- **Step1:** Pass Nth number of arguments using [**spread**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax (in this code it is `...arg`) and this arg is an array.
- **Step2:** Create an object of `all_messages` and try to find one key of `arg` from `all_messages` using [**find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- **Step3:** If find from message list, return that keyed value from `all_messages`.
- **Step4:** Set default value `A` if `all_message` doesn't include any value of `arg`.

```js
const status = (...arg) => {
    const all_messages = {error: 'error', C: 'C', B: 'B'};
    const message = arg.find(key => !!all_messages[key])
    return message ? message : 'A'
}

console.log(status('F', 'F'))
console.log(status('C', 'A'))
console.log(status('C', 'C', 'C', 'C'))
console.log(status('error', 'error', 'error', 'error'))
console.log(status('B', 'B', 'B'))
```

Comment: @hrabal, according to your post I updated this answer. You can try a bit now.

Answer (score 0):

You could write one function for that instead of three. Something like:

```
const statusFilter = (dataArray) ...
```

Compare the values of the Array. If they're all the same, return the value, if not, return A.

Answer (score 0):

just use array as param:

```
const statusFilters = data => {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    if (data.includes("error")) return "error";
    else if (data.includes("C")) return "C";
    else if (data.includes("B")) return "B";
    else return "A";
  }
};

statusFilters([data1, data2, data3 ...]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
const statusFilter = (...args) => {
  if (args.indexOf('error') !== -1) {
    return 'error';
  } else if (args.indexOf('C') !== -1) {
    return 'C';
  } else if (args.indexOf('B') !== -1) {
    return 'B';
  } else {
    return 'A';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to have an array of statuses you want to check against ordered by priority based on what you want to return first. In your example, the order seems to be `error, c, b, a` You can then loop through that array returning that status if a match is found. At the very end, if no matches were found, return the default value, which is `a` in your case.

```js
// In order of priority
const statuses = [ 'error', 'C', 'B', 'A' ]

const statusFilter = (...args) => {  
  for (let status of statuses) {
     if(args.find(v => v === status))
        return status;
  }
  return 'A'
}

console.log(statusFilter('error', 'B', 'A'))
console.log(statusFilter('C', 'B', 'A'))
console.log(statusFilter('B', 'B', 'A'))
console.log(statusFilter('A', 'A', 'A'))
```